# Empty table body in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm a newbie to jQuery, so, please, don't judge me for my dumb question.
What I'm trying to achieve is fill datatable with exchange rates, sourced by [API](https://openexchangerates.org/).

So, I managed to construct datatable, but its body is empty and there're no errors in the console, it's just "**loading...**" message where my data is supposed to be.

Searching for similar topics just didn't get any results. I would be thankful for your help, because I'm banging my head against that wall for 2 days already.

```html
<head> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>       
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <table id="rates"></table> 
</body>
```

```js
var key = '8366e7a49e014c729111a0ac6e5c7d9d';
var url = 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=';
var dataTable = $('#rates').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  ajax: {
    url: url + key
  },
  columns: [{
    title: 'currency'
  },{
    title: 'rate'
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your data is structured improperly. Each data entry must correspond to DataTables row, so your code should be something like:

```js
var key = '8366e7a49e014c729111a0ac6e5c7d9d';
var url = 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=';

var dataTable = $('#rates').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  ajax: {
    url: url+key,
    dataSrc: function(data){
        let apiData = [];
        $.each(data.rates, function(index, entry){
          apiData.push({currency:index, rate:entry});
        });
        return apiData.slice(0,10);
      }
    },
    columns: [
      {title:'currency', data:'currency'},
      {title:'rate', data:'rate'}
    ]
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="rates"></table>
</body>
</html>
```